# Illustrator is applying a fill to all areas and not just the area I would like?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a REAL newbie question but if I do not ask then I will not learn.

I am using Photoshop and Illustrator CC2018 and I am in no way an experienced user.

In photoshop I designed a Letter D.

I used the remove background tool to remove the areas outside of the D and in the center.

I then created Workpaths and exported them to Illustrator.

I opened Illustrator, opened the workpath, selected it and tried to apply a fill but as you can see from the example image the fill is being applied to the center of the letter too.

My question is what am I doing wrong?

Is there a way I can maybe click only on the area I want filled?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
[image: Example]

Comment: *why* are you making you "D" shape in Photoshop first instead of making it in Illustrator? Maybe I'm missing something, or maybe you're just practicing, but I can't think of any reason I would use that workflow. You received good advice on how to solve that particular problem – I'm just wondering if maybe you could use some help in deciding which program is "the right tool for the job", which may make your life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: I like using Photoshop as I can edit or create my font pixel by pixel which at my level of experience (ie: newbie) gives me more control but when I have learnt Illustrator better than my current level then I hope to move completely into that.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't doing anything *wrong*.

In order to have a hole or counter in a shape you need to make a **compound path** in Illustrator.

Select both paths, and choose **`Object > Compound path > Make`** from the menu. That *should* knockout the center of the D.

---

If that doesn't work. **Undo**. And then hit the **Minus Front** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Window > Pathfinder).

---

If *that* still doesn't work, `Undo` and hit the **Minus Back** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

---

The Pathfinder operations do the same thing as the Compound Path menu item and will also result in a compound path (with a little extra "fool-proof-ery"), but without knowing how the paths are *specifically* stacked, I can't tell if you need Minus Front or Minus Back.